# How to make variable of a function global within a class?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, global-variables

So, I'm having some trouble to understand how I can access the value of a variable of a function from another function within a class.

```
    import Tkinter as tk, tkFileDialog

    class test:
        def __init__(self):
            root = tk.Tk()
            song_button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Select Song', fg = 'blue', command = self.loadfile).pack()
            #how do I access the value of filename now?

        def loadfile(self):
            filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("allfiles","*"),("pythonfiles","*.py")])
```

Comment: You want to access `filename` in the initializer? That'll be called before `loadfile()` can ever be called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now filename is just a local variable in the `loadfile` function.  You need to make filename an attribute of the object.  Do `self.filename = ...`, then in other methods you can access it as `self.filename`.

(In this particular case what you're asking seems a bit odd, since `loadfile` won't have been called at the time you seem to want to access `filename`, so `filename` won't even exist.  But this is the general idea.  No matter what, you obviously need to call the function where the variable is defined before you can do anything with it.)